# Architecture specific debian package

Tags: package-management, packaging, debian

I have created debian package XYZ.

It has control file which look's like

```
Package: XYZ
Version: 1.0
Section: kernel
Priority: optional
Architecture: i386     
Depends:
Installed-Size: 1024
```

I just have a question ,

1. When I build this package on some machine it say's 
   `dpkg-deb: building package XYZ:i386`.
   But when I build same package on some other machine It says 
   `dpkg-deb: building package XYZ`.
   Why this difference?
2. On deinstallation I am facing same issue the package which was build with name XYZ:i386 requires `dpkg -r XYZ:i386` to uninstall it .why?

Cant we just say dpkg -r XYZ?

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg-deb: building package XYZ:i386` means you are building it in 32 bit Ubuntu machine.

`dpkg-deb: building package XYZ:` means you are building it in a 64 bit Ubuntu machine.

`dpkg -r <package-name>`

```
 The above command will remove the package-name.deb file.
```

Comment: yes,you are correct.

Comment: you are asking how to remove xyz:i386 package with `dpkg -r xyz`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11945/discussion-between-captain-and-avinash-raj)